# Can I create Django models automatically?

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-deployment, rdbms

I'm working on a resume website with Django in which, for the skill section I defined a model as below,

```
from django.db import models


class Skills(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But, for example, if I add a skill "Python" through admin in this model, I want to add a few slides for the skill, each containing a image and a paragraph, to give detailed information about my skill.

In other words, I want to create a table for each skill I'll add with columns named image, and description.

Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Why do you not just add those fields to your model?

Comment: I don't think that **Relational Database** are designed to add some table at the fly. Try **NoSql** like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django)

Comment: @yagus I don't know, how many skills and how many slides I will for each skill. So creating a model for every skill manually is not very practical in my situation.

Comment: You'd create a new model that contains columns such as image and text for your paragraph and a ForeignKey to your Skills model.

Comment: eg: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ - if you imagine your Skills model is the Reporter in that example then you create a new model called something like SkillDetail (or whatever you want) like the example shows in the Article model

Comment: SO isn't great for tutorials... the above link has examples and explanations - I highly recommend going through that a few times

Comment: @HIMANSHUKAWALE it looks like you've already been given an answer that'll work - but I'd still recommend reading through the documentation so you understand it properly as that understanding will come in useful later where you'll likely come across similar modelling problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one skill can have multiple 'slides', you need to create another model with a foreignkey([ManyToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)) to your skills model.

for example:

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=3)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SkillDetail(models.Model):
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skills, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    description = models.TextField()
```